# Is it possible to virtualize using ips through a GRE Tunnel?

Tags: networking, server, virtualization

Today I am writing here to know if it would be possible to use ips that are on another machine, like, this way:

I have DDoS Protected IPs on MACHINE1, and I'd like to use them to virtualize my MACHINE2 which isn't DDoS protected, could I use a GRE Tunnel to use those IPs on the MACHINE2 even though they are assigned to MACHINE1?

Comment: Why not NAT Machine 2 within Machine1, and use firewall rules for port forwarding on Machine 1 to the internal IP on Machine 2?  (This is standard NAT, like a standard router, which would be basically what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: Yes but basically I don't know how to do that actually.

Comment: I still didn't found a solution, what can I do?